# Obtain references to numpy array elements by condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So, I have a target numpy array, say

```
a = np.array([3, 7, 9, 3, 5])
```

and I have a condition array, e.g.

```
c = np.array([False, False, True, True, False])
```

and I'd like to obtain array `b`, specified by `c`

```
>>> b
array([9,3])
```

**such that if I change it, `a` also changes**. For example:

```
>>> b[0]=2
>>> b
array([2,3])
>>> a
array([3, 7, 2, 3, 5])
```

I've tried something like that:

```
>>> b = np.compress(c,a)
>>> b
array([9, 3])
>>> b[0]=2
>>> b
array([2, 3])
>>> a
array([3, 7, 9, 3, 5])
```

But it does not work, `a` is still same, `np.compress()` returns a copy. Also I had no success with this code:

```
b=a[np.where(c)]
```

Is there any analog of `np.compress()` that returns references, not copy? 
Thank you!

Comment: `b` will always be a copy; never a view. Masked array may be the best way of applying the mask 'on-the-fly'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that could probably fit your needs is `numpy` "masking":

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([3,7, 9, 3, 5])
>>> c = np.array([False, False, True, True, False])
>>> b = np.ma.array(a,mask=~c)
```

Note I had to take the elementwise negation of `c`: `~c`, since `True` will be interpreted as "this element should be masked" wheras you want the opposite - this element should be unmasked. Notice now that `b` acts how you want when you do operations on it:

```
>>> b
masked_array(data = [-- -- 9 3 --],
             mask = [ True  True False False  True],
       fill_value = 999999)
>>> b.sum()
12
>>> (2*b)
masked_array(data = [-- -- 18 6 --],
             mask = [ True  True False False  True],
       fill_value = 999999)

>>> (2*b).sum()
```

And furthermore, it is working on a view of `a`, so changing `a` changes `b`:

```
>>> a
array([3, 7, 9, 3, 5])
>>> a[2] = 42
>>> a
array([ 3,  7, 42,  3,  5])
>>> b
masked_array(data = [-- -- 42 3 --],
             mask = [ True  True False False  True],
       fill_value = 999999)

>>> b.sum()
45
```

The reverse also work, albeit, the index doesn't change:

```
>>> b[2] = 88
>>> a
array([ 3,  7, 88,  3,  5])
>>> b
masked_array(data = [-- -- 88 3 --],
             mask = [ True  True False False  True],
       fill_value = 999999)

>>>
```

Unfortunately, python is relatively high-level, so working with raw references is not straightforward.